# ninguna sobrecarga para el metodo reverse toma 0 argumentos en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

El caso es que intento construir este if:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me sale los siguientes errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene alguna idea? estas son las variables que estoy utilizando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el código debería estar en formato de texto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probablemente te falta incluir el namespace de Linq

```
using System.Linq;
```

El método `Reverse` que quieres usar es un método de extensión que se encuentra en ese namespace.  La clase de array en C# también tiene un método `Reverse` pero funciona diferente y recibe parámetros, es por eso el error que estás viendo.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon , muchisimas gracias.

Comment: estas seguro que con solo agregar System.Linq se resuelve ?

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar un `Split()` estas generando un `array` de `string` por lo tanto aplica el

[Array.Reverse()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=netframework-3.5) y no el [Reverse()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.reverse?view=netframework-3.5) de `List<>`

Si analiza la documentacion de estos veras que el array requiere obligatoriamente parametros, mientras que el del `List<>` puede definirse sin este

Entiendo que para usar `List<>` se requiere `System.Collections.Generic` el cual quizas tengas, pero deberias pasar el string[] a List usando

```
string respuesta = reader["respuesta"].ToString().Replace('+', ' ');
List<string> respuestas = respuesta.Split('/').ToList();

respuestas.Reverse();
```

al usar el ToList() obtienes un `List<>` en lugar de un `string[]`

Una aclaracion, el `Reverse()` devuelve `void`, por lo tanto no hay una respuesta, sino que revierte sobre la misma variable, separa el codigo en varias lineas para poder entenderlo